# mysqldump --where does not work inside shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I prepare mysqldump command in a shell script like follows (simplified example)

```
command="mysqldump -v -uuser -ppass base1 table1 --where=\"id=1 or id=2\""
```

When I echo the command

```
echo $command
```

in shell script it returns correct mysqldump command

```
mysqldump -v -uuser -ppass base1 table1 --where="id=1 or id=2"
```

that I can copy and run and it works well.

When I try to run it from inside of the shell script

```
$command
```

it seemingly does not pass quotation marks to the command and therefore cannot execute conditional dump, saying

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "or"
```

It works in shell script if the --where attribute does not contain spaces but not otherwise. I have tried using single quotes, backticks, escapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `command` variable contains the correct command to run and `echo $command` shows this. But because the argument of `--where` contains whitespaces, when `$command` is evaluated these whitespaces make the shell parse the command line in a different way than you think.

The solution is simple. If you have composed the command line as string in the `command` variable, use the [`eval` internal shell command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) to execute it:

```
eval $command
```